# FOSUserBundle confirmation mail

Tags: php, symfony, email, fosuserbundle

I have an issue , i'm trying to send a confirmation mail using fosuserbundle mail confirmation , the email after registration is sent, but it is not correct :

It contains as subject : **registration.email.subject**

And as message : **registration.email.message**

After registration , path for : /register/check-email render me this content :

```
layout.login
registration.flash.user_created
registration.check_email
```

My config.yml looks like :

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  smtp
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    port:       587
    host:       mail.xx.xxx
    username:   xxx
    password:   xxx
    disable_delivery:   false
    spool: {type: memory }

fos_user: 
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel' 
    firewall_name: main 
    user_class: App\MyBundle\Entity\Prestataire
    registration: 
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true 
            template:   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig        
            from_email: 
                address: xx@xx.xx
                sender_name: xx
    service:
            mailer:               fos_user.mailer.default
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: have you enable translation in your config.yml ?

Comment: do you mean this code line ?
       #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }

Comment: Yes ! I think you need to enable it to make it works

Comment: oh thanks ! that worked ! but i dont know its meaning !

Comment: The translator component let you use translations with Symfony. FOSUserBundle use internally this component to fetch the correct translation. I.e the string 'registration.flash.user_created' will be translated into the correct string according to your current locale !

Comment: Got it thank you men ! Do you know btw how to disable it ? those things like log in word in the register page content ?

Comment: You need to override FOSUserBundle templates and change it to whatever you want. See the docs for this bundle.